# No se encontro la clase mongo

Tags: php, mongodb

Estoy teniendo un problema con mongodb, instale el driver de mongodb para php que se llama php_mongodb.dll lo que coloque en las extensiones de php en el xampp.

Al crear la conexión con php a mongo me dice que la clase mongo no se encuentra.
En el php.ini coloque la extensión php_mongodb.dll y aun aparece el error.

Alguien me podria decir que esta mal.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Mongo' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\mongo\prueba1.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\mongo\prueba1.php on line 3
```

Codigo de la conexion aqui

```
<?php

$mongo= new Mongo();
$db = $mongo->selectDB("prueba");
$usuarios= $mongo->selectCollection("prueba","usuarios");
$usuario=array("usuarios"=>"antonio","pass"=>"123456");
$usuarios->insert($usuario);
$cursor =$usuarios->find();

foreach ($cursor as $usuario){
 print_r($usuario);
}
  ?>
```

Comment: Agrega tu código por favor

Comment: listo, ya lo agregue.

Comment: Por favor tu código como texto, ahora por otro lado esa instancia de la clase Mongo, ¿cómo va a saber PHP de donde obtenerla?

Comment: Es decir ahi debería existir un require del archivo donde existe dicha clase

Comment: pues yo he leido sobre eso y segun solo con el driver de mongo en el php, se reconocia, pero nada.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como realizar una conexion php con mongodb](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/344854/como-realizar-una-conexion-php-con-mongodb)