# Como realizar una conexion php con mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb

Quiero hacer una conexion a la base de datos mongo con php, me podrian indicar el paso a paso.
Yo trabajo con el xampp en el localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trataré de explicartelo lo mas sencillo posible:

## Primer paso.

Descargar el driver MongoDB para PHP.

- Vas a [DLL MongoDB para PHP](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb/1.7.4/windows)
- Eliges la versión que tienes de PHP 7.4, 7.3 o 7.2 u otra versión.
- Lo descargas Claramente.

### Segundo Paso.

- Descomprimes el archivo descargado, entras a la carpeta y copias el archivo llamado php_mongodb.dll.
- Vas al directorio C:\xampp\php y entras en la carpeta ext y aqui pegas el archivo php_mongodb.dll.
- Ahora vas al archivo php.ini
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- Dentro del archivo añades esta linea

```
extension=php_mongodb.dll
```

- Reinicias el xampp. Ya tienes la extensión instalada.

#### Tercer paso.

- Entras a tu proyecto y con composer descargas mongodb.

```
composer require mongodb/mongodb
```

- Código de prueba para ver si va todo satisfactoriamente.

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Creo un alias del namespace
use MongoDB\Client as Mongo;

// Crea una instancia del driver MongoDB
$mongo= new Mongo("mongodb://localhost:27017");

// Selecciona la base de datos llamada "pruebas"
$dbPruebas = $mongo->prueba;

// Selecciona la colección llamada "usuarios" de la base de datos "pruebas"
$usuarios = $dbPruebas->usuarios;

// Inserta un nuevo usuario en la colección
$usuarios->insertOne(["usuario" => "antonio", "pass" => "123456"]);

// Coge todos los documentos de la colección
$cursor = $usuarios->find()->toArray();

// Recorre el array de documentos
foreach ($cursor as $usuario){
 print_r($usuario);
}
?>
```

Comment: ahora sale un error en el insertar, pero muchisimas gracias, por fin alguien me da una respuesta.

Comment: Que error te sale, ¿ Podrías mostrarlo ?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method MongoDB\Collection::insert() in C:\xampp\htdocs\mongo\prueba1.php:16 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\mongo\prueba1.php on line 16

Comment: llamalo insertOne en vez de insert y prueba a ver.

Comment: Si, ya salio, muchisimas gracias. Oye, quisiera preguntarte, sabes como presentar mejor los datos? como con bootstrap? o tendria que publicar otra pregunta?

Answer (score 1):

Para usar el controlador PHP de MongoDB, descárguelo del siguiente sitio: https://s3.amazonaws.com/drivers.mongodb.org/php/index.html

Debes descargar la última versión del mismo. Ahora descomprima el archivo y coloque php_mongo.dll en su directorio de extensión de PHP.

```
extension = php_mongo.dll
```

Ahora en un archivo de clase php insertamos el siguiente código

```
<?php
   // Crear una nueva instancia del conector
   $mongo = new MongoClient();

   echo "Conexion exitosa"; //porque no hubo excepciones

   // seleccionamos una base de datos
   $db = $mongo->base_de_datos;

   echo "base_de_datos seleccionada"; //porque no hubo excepciones
?>
```

Ahora si la conexión fue exitosa deberías obtener lo siguiente:

```
Conexión exitosa
base_de_datos seleccionada
```

Para crear una colección puedes guiarte de lo siguiente:

```
<?php
   // conectarse
   $mongo = new MongoClient();

   //seleccionar
   $db = $mongo->db; 

   $coleccion = $db->createCollection("mi_coleccion");

   echo "Coleccion Creada Exitosamente";
?>
```

Para insertar un documento

```
<?php
   $mongo = new MongoClient();
   $db = $mongo->db;
   $coleccion = $db->mi_coleccion;

   $documento = array( 
      "titulo" => "MongoDB", 
      "descripcion" => "base de datos", 
      "registros" => 100
   );

   $coleccion->insert($documento);

   echo "Documento insertado";
?>
```

Para actualizar un documento

```
<?php
   $mongo = new MongoClient();
   $db = $mongo->db;
   $coleccion = $db->mi_coleccion;

   $coleccion->update(array("titulo"=>"MongoDB"), 
      array('$set'=>array("titulo"=>"Tutorial MongoDB")));

   // Ahora verificamos con find()
   $cursor = $coleccion->find();

   foreach ($cursor as $documento) {
      echo $documento["titulo"] . "\n";
   }
?>
```

Y para borrar un documento

```
<?php
   $mongo = new MongoClient();
   $db = $mongo->db;
   $coleccion = $db->mi_coleccion;

   $coleccion->remove(array("titulo"=>"Tutorial MongoDB"), false);

   // Ahora verificamos
   $cursor = $coleccion->find();

   foreach ($cursor as $documento) {
      echo $documento["titulo"] . "\n";
   }
?>
```

Saludos.

Comment: muchas gracias.